I'm developing a web application using django and ajax for checklist. I have total of 140 checklist
I'm developing a web application using django and ajax for checklist. I have total of 140 checklist each checklist have header(meta data about that particular checklist), body of the checklist, and signature footer where certain users can click the ticket box and close the checklist. These 140 checklist are of 28 different types with different structures. Now I stored that each checklist as json data and created different templates and views for each types. Is it good way or is there any other better way to do this.. I'm a new developer and I can't get satisfied with my approach to this solution like there is a better solution.
As I'm a new developer. Even though I can get solution to my problems but there is a feeling that is not the best solution until I get the best solution I can't get satisfied with this approach

you're not speaking about models/database so it's hard to set a common ground for understanding. your 28 types/views/templates look like what django calls models. and 28 models for 140 objects looks terribly overkill. at the same time, you're calling all these 140 objects checklists which suggests they indeed have a lot in common. and one model is fine. but 28 views for a model probably is not. so i think you should decimate your types, focus on what they have in common. and if you intend to have more than 140 checklists use a database, it's more efficient

It is actually just 2 models one to store the json data when the user creates the instance it copies the json and put it in another models where it can be edited. And I used js for form validation.
